# How to enable suspend on exit in CruchBang Linux?

Tags: linux, crunchbang, openbox

I use CrunchBang Linux and the Openbox window manager which is  very minimal. The **Exit** command on the openbox main menu opens this window which does not list **Suspend**.

[image]

[image]

Currently , I have to login as root in terminal and issue this command to suspend my machine :

> **root@Tron:/home/aswin#** pm-suspend

This is rather time consuming and I would like to add **suspend** to the **exit**   menu.Is there any way I can add **suspend**  to the **exit** menu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crunchbang seems to come with a differently configured Openbox than what I get when installing on Debian. My Exit menu is not as pretty as yours and has even fewer options:

[image]

[image]

So, it looks like your Openbox is configured to launch a different exit menu than mine. I might be able to help more if you figure out exactly what it launches and what it's called. In the meantime, as a workaround, you can add a `Suspend` menu entry to your menu:

1. Set up `sudo` to allow you to run `pm-suspend` with no password. Open a terminal, run `visudo` and add this line (assuming your username is `aswin`):

   ```
   aswin ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/pm-suspend
   ```

   If you're not used to `vi`, you can also edit the file `/etc/sudoers` directly but using `visudo` is safer.
2. Add a new menu entry to the Openbox menu that runs `sudo pm-suspend`. Edit the menu file at `~/.config/openbox/menu.xml` (if the file is not there, copy it from `/etc/xdg/openbox/menu.xml`) and add these lines:

   ```
   <separator />
   <item label="Suspend">
    <action name="Execute"><execute>sudo pm-suspend</execute></action>
   </item>
   ```

Now, restart Openbox and your menu will include the new `Suspend` entry which should suspend your computer with no need for a password:

[image]

Comment: this solves the problem even though copying /etc/xdg/openbox/menu.xml changed the contents of my main menu.

Comment: @Ash strange, you probably already _had_ a `~/.config/openbox/menu.xml` and overwrote it with the default.

Comment: no probs.I always used alt+f2 for all other programs.